# How to implement synchronization b/w two database tables?

Tags: mysql, oracle, hibernate, postgresql

I have two database tables. One of them is on my local server and another one is on any external System. How to update local server table(initially both are same) when there is any change in external System table using Hibernate. I have to implement this on all databases(i.e. sql/oracle)

Comment: I think you avoid trying to sync two separate databases as it invites a plethora of problems.  For instance, how can you handle rolling back data in real time?  Instead, maybe consider running a batch job each night to move a snapshot over to the backup database.

Comment: This is not called synchronisation, this is called replication. Most rdbms products have replication functions, so you do not need hibernate. The external database will be the master, the local will be the slave.

Comment: what about a trigger? is that a big table?

Answer (score 0):

That is replication
either use batch process periodically or implement replication for your database 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html

**you can also use FEDERATED table concept**